# Genus und Etymologie von 'Treff'

Tags: etymology, gender

Gestern kam in einem Gespräch die Diskussion auf, welches Genus »Treff« hat. Laut Duden und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Treff) heißt es »Der Treff«, es gibt aber auch [andere](https://deutsch.heute-lernen.de/grammatik/der-die-das/treff) Seiten, die anderes behaupten.

»Treff« scheint nach Blick auf die Wortverlaufskurve in DWDS auch kein neueres Wort zu sein, sondern früher sogar gebräuchlicher zu sein als heute. Es stammt also nicht kürzlich aus dem Englischen, sodass eine Argumentation mit "bei eingedeutschten Wörtern wird (meist) das Genus genommen, der dem entsprechenden deutschen Wort entspricht" passen würde (hier evtl. Treffpunkt - das Treffen würde nicht passen).

Darum stelle ich diese Fragen:

- Lässt sich das Genus von »der Treff« erklären oder irgendwoher ableiten?
- Gibt es da mundartlich abweichende Nutzung?

Comment: Von welchem englischen Wort sollte denn wohl "Treff" kommen, wenn es denn das täte?

Comment: Aengl. *thorp*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Treff* kann auch als Substantivierung von *treffen* verstanden werden, analog zu anderen Substantivierungen, die von der Wurzel des Verbs abgeleitet sind, wie etwa rufen / Ruf, laufen / Lauf usw. Diese Substantivierungen sind überwiegend männlich. Es gibt allerdings Ausnahmen wie spielen / das Spiel.

Dagegen ließe sich vielleicht einwenden, dass *Treff* dann eher *Treffen* bedeuten sollte als *Treffpunkt*. *Treff* kann allerdings auch als "regelmäßiges Treffen" verstanden werden.

Comment: Ich finde dies eigentlich die bisher bei weitem beste Erklärung. Simpel, gradaus, und logisch. Warum "Treff" eine Verkürzung von "Treffpunkt" sein soll, erklärt sich mir nämlich nicht. Lt. Pfeifer gab's das Wort schon im Mittelhochdeutschen, *Treffpunkt* ist sicher neuer.

Comment: Beim DWDS (Dumme Weiten, doofe Seiten?) sind viele Beispielsätze aufgeführt die zum Teil klaren Ortsbezug haben (als Treff diente der Bahnhof) und zum Teil klar ein Ereignis referenzieren (die Treffs der VoPo in Schulen...). Ich würde kann auch beide Verwendungen bestätigen. Ähnlich kann man auch mit "Oper" den Ort o. das Ereignis meinen. Mit Bahnhof weniger, auch Stadion nicht, aber Karneval, was zudem ein Zeitraum/Zeitpunkt sein kann.

Answer (score 4):

Wie so oft ist der Kontext entscheidend, der leider in der Fragestellung – wie so oft – nicht mitgeliefert wird.

Ein Blick in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Treff) oder [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Treff) zeigt, dass es von diesem Wort zwei Homonyme gibt, wovon eines in zwei unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen verwendet wird. Daher haben wir es mit insgsamt drei verschiedenen Bedeutungen zu tun. (Der Duden kennt sogar noch eine vierte Bedeutung, die aber veraltet ist, siehe unten.) Leider liefert die Fragestellung keinerlei Hinweise darauf, welche dieser Bedeutung gemeint sein könnte.

1. **Kartenfarbe bei Spielkarten**

   > Siegessicher knallte Kurt den König auf den Tisch, aber er war zu betrunken und hatte sich geirrt. Es war kein Pik sondern ein **Treff.**

   Das Wort stammt vom französischen *»trèfle«* ab, was auf deutsch *»Klee«* oder *»Kleeblatt«* bedeutet und eigentlich viel besser die Form des Symbols beschreibt als das deutsche Wort *»Kreuz«.*
   Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Treff#Substantiv,_n) und [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Treff_Spielkarte) ist dieses Wort sächlich: *»das Treff«,* Im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Treff#2) steht, dass es sächlich oder weiblich sein kann, also auch *»die Treff«.*
2. **Synonym für *Treffpunkt* (also für einen Ort)**

   > Sonja erschien beim ausgemachten **Treff,** aber das Blind Date fand nicht statt, weil außer ihr niemand dort erschien.
   > Der nördliche Treppenaufgang in der Einkaufspassage ist ein beliebter **Treff** für Jugendliche.

   Das Wort ist eine Verkürzung des deutschen Wortes *»Treffpunkt«* und erbt von diesem Wort das grammatische Geschlecht. Es ist daher männlich. Darin sind sich [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Treff#Substantiv,_m) (Bedeutung [2]) [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Treff#1) (Bedeutung 2.) und [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Treff_Treffpunkt) (Bedeutung b) einig.
3. **Synonym für *Meeting, Treffen* (also für ein einzelnes oder ein sich wiederholendes Ereignis)**

   > Bei dem **Treff** mit Peter habe ich erfahren, dass Walter gar nicht Oslo war.
   > Die Seniorenrunde hat jeden zweiten Dienstag einen **Treff** in der Waldschenke.

   In dieser Bedeutung ist das Wort eine Verkürzung von *»das Treffen«* und sollte daher eigentlich sächlich sein. Alle Wörterbücher stimmen aber darüber überein, dass das Wort in dieser Bedeutugn männlich ist: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Treff#Substantiv,_m) (Bedeutung [1]) [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Treff#1) (Bedeutung 1.) und [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Treff_Treffpunkt) (Bedeutung a)
   Ich wäre nicht überrascht, wenn dieses Wort in dieser Bedeutung doch das eine oder andere Mal als sächliches Wort verwendet werden würde. Ich würde das dann nicht für falsch halten.

---

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Treff_Schlag) führt noch eine weitere Bedeutung an, die dort als *»veraltet«* markiert ist und in den anderen Wörterbüchern fehlt. Diese Bedeutung entspricht *Schlag, Hieb, Niederlage.* Beispielsätze fehlen, das Geschlecht wird im Duden als *männlich* deklariert.

---

Die Frage nach mundartlich abweichenden Nutzungen kann ich nicht beantworten. Ich kann dazu nur beisteuern, dass das Wort *»Treff«* in den in Ost-Österreich gesprochenen Dialekten nicht verwendet wird und auch im österreichischen Standarddeutsch ist es mir noch nicht begegnet.

Wenn die Kartenfarbe gemeint ist, ziehen wir Österreicher es bei französischen Karten vor von *»Kreuz«* zu sprechen. Viele traditionelle österreichische Kartenspiele werden aber ohnehin nicht mit französischen sondern mit [doppeldeutschen](https://schnopsn.com/doppeldeutsche-karten) Spielkarten gespielt, und da gibt es andere Kartenfarben (nur *Herz* gibt es in beiden Varianten). Die doppeldeutsche Farbe, die dem französischen Kreuz/Treff entspricht, ist *»Eichel«.*

Wenn wir in Österreich von einem Treffpunkt (also dem Ort) sprechen, verwenden wir das Wort *»Treffpunkt«.* Wenn das Ereignis gemeint ist, sagen wir *»Treffen«,* in einem Business-Kontext aber auch *»Meeting«.*

Das Wort *»Treff«* verwenden wir nie alleinstehend, sondern höchstens in Komposita (*»Seniorentreff, Schwulentreff, Sandlertreff«*) (österreichisch *Sandler* = deutschländisch *Gammler*).

Comment: Anmerkung zu Spielkartenfarben: Auch in Deutschland verwenden Kartenspieler für die Farben des französischen Blatts heute üblicherweise die deutschen Namen: Kreuz, Pik, Herz, Karo. Ich kenne nur eine einzige Ausnahme von dieser Regel, nämlich Bridgespieler, die in Deutschland regelmäßig Treff, Pik, Coeur, und Karo benutzen.

Comment: Du leitest aus "Synonym für Treffpunkt" (was so auch in den von dir zitierten WB steht) kurzerhand "abgeleitet von Treffpunkt" ab - Das steht da aber nicht.

Comment: @tofro: 1. Ich habe geschrieben: *»Das Wort ist eine Verkürzung des deutschen Wortes ›Treffpunkt‹«.* Dabei habe ich nicht behauptet, dass das irgendwo anders stehen würde. 2. Wiktionary und Duden machen gar keine Angaben darüber, wo das Wort herkommt. Das DWDS verweist aber bei mehreren Wörtern, darunter [Treff](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Treff#1) und [Treffpunkt](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Treffpunkt) (aber u.a. auch  bei*treffend, betroffen, unübertroffen, zutreffen*) auf die Etymologie des Verbs *»treffen«,* was man wohl so interpretieren muss, dass all diese Wörter eng miteinander verwandt sind.

Comment: Die Spielkartenfarbe heißt im Bridge - auch in Österreich - "Treff", nicht "Kreuz". Und zwar ausschließlich. Bei anderen Kartenspielen (Tarock, Preference, ...) ist mir sowohl "Treff" wie auch "Kreuz" in Ostösterreich etwa gleich häufig begegnet.

Comment: @bakunin: Ich habe noch nie Bridge gespielt und kenne auch keine Bridge-Spieler.

Comment: zu 4 (veraltet) fiele mir noch vor Schlag, Hieb natürlich Treffer ein. Ansonsten +1, obwohl ich mich der Substantivierung von "Treffen" statt Verkürzung von "Treffen" oder gar "Treffpunkt" anschließe. Abkürzungen werden bekanntlich mit Punkt geschrieben.

Comment: @userunknown: Verkürzungen sind keine Abkürzungen und werden daher ohne Punkt geschrieben (Diskothek → Disko oder Demonstration → Demo oder auch Universität → Uni und Mathematik → Mathe)

Comment: Punkt für Dich.

Answer (score -1):

Als verkürzte Form vom (in DWDS) angegebenen Synonym **Treffpunkt** halte ich das Maskulinum für korrekt und sehe da auch keine plausible Alternative.

Wenn es um die Bedeutung *Veranstaltung* oder die Verkürzung von **Treffen** geht, könnte ich mit mit Neutrum eher anfreunden, aber da weder Duden noch DWDS eine bedeutungsabhängige Unterscheidung angeben...

(Die Spielkartenfarbe habe ich nicht betrachtet.)

Comment: Spielkartenfarben sind (bei französischem Bild) neutral, *das Treff* (so wie *das Herz/Coeur*, *das Pik*, *das Karo*). Doppeldeutsches Bild ist komplizierter: *die Schelle* (=Karo), *der Spaten* (auch *das Blatt* genannt, =Pik), *das Herz* (=Herz), *die Eichel* (=Treff)

Comment: Die Frage dreht sich um eine Erklärung des Genus, nicht um die Frage, was das Genus ist.

Comment: Gibt es Belege für die Verkürzungshypothese? Kennst Du andere Beispiele von gesicherten Verkürzungen und eine Regel, die besagt, dass solche Verkürzungen immer geschlechtserhaltend sind?